# How to make a CSS transition work "backwards"?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I have this transition on hover, that makes a border at the bottom of the element that is being hovered over. All is well there, but when the mouse leaves the element, the border simply disappears, while I want it to "retract" back again. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOoMGQ)

HTML:

```
<div class="object">

<p>Object</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
background-color: #222;
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 30pt;
}

p {
 width: 200px;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 70px;
text-align: center;
transition: 0.2s border-bottom;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s border-bottom;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 50px;
}

p:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```

How would I go about doing this, as simple as possible?
Thank you ;3

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Transitions work in both directions automatically.

The problem you are experiencing is that `border-style` is not a property that can be animated so it changes instantly.

This means that when you hover it, it becomes `solid` instantly and then spends time becoming `5px`.

But when you unhover it, it becomes `none` instantly and you can't see the width animating.

Make the default (non-hovered) state explicit so that the `border-width` is the only thing that changes when you hover it.

Add:

```
border-bottom: 0px solid white;
```

to the rules for `p`.

Comment: Oh, Uhm, embarrasing. Oh well, you learn something new every day, I suppose. Anyways, Thank you ;3

Comment: It took me some head scratching to figure out what was happening there.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this could help, but in my case I just did like this:

Over:

```
.<nameOfClass>:hover{
 transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

No over:

```
.<nameOfClass>:not(:hover){
 transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `border-bottom: 0px solid white` to `p`. Css wants to know where to transition back to! :D

Comment: Don't put a low effort copy paste of the top answer as your own.

Comment: Sorry for that, but the moment I clicked add answer the first post wasn't there ;)

Answer (score -1):

for transition add an animate class to the element you want the transition

```
.animate 
 { 
  transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
 }
```

Now when you add this class to your element it will make transition in both hover and hover out.

Comment: That won't help at all. There is nothing special about having a class that only applies the transition property and the existing code in the question already applied that property with the rest of the rules for that element.